# Cannot create direcory in gDrive throguh Colab

Tags: directory, google-colaboratory

This is my first approach on Codelab. With the code below I would like to create the directories of my projects, but until now I am unsucessful.

```
from os.path import join
from google.colab import drive
ROOT = "/content/drive"
drive.mount(ROOT)

mainDirectory = "My Drive/Algorithm Trading"
PROJECT_PATH = join(ROOT)

for i in range(1, 12, 1):
```

> `BeginningStr = ""`
>
> `EndingStr = ""`
>   `if i < 10 :`
>
> > `BeginningStr = "000" + str(i) + " - "`
> >
> > `EndingStr = "Chapter0" + str(i)`
>
> `else:`
>
> > `BeginningStr = "00" + str(i) + " - "`
> >
> > `EndingStr = "Chapter" + str(i)`
>
> `PROJ = BeginningStr + EndingStr`
>
> `PROJECT_PATH = join(ROOT, mainDirectory, PROJ)`
>
> `!mkdir "{PROJECT_PATH}"`

The following is what I get as answer:

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0001 - Chapter01’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0002 - Chapter02’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0003 - Chapter03’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0004 - Chapter04’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0005 - Chapter05’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0006 - Chapter06’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0007 - Chapter07’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0008 - Chapter08’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0009 - Chapter09’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0010 - Chapter10’: No such file or directory

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/content/drive/My Drive/Algorithm Trading/0011 - Chapter11’: No such file or directory

Could you help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
!mkdir $PROJECT_PATH
```

Because the ! call the shell command. You want to pass python variable data_path to it. Otherwise it will just make a directory name "data_path"